# Linq Group by Values in a list

Tags: c#, linq

So Currently I have this TrackingInfo class which contains an ID and a list of EmailActionIDs, which is an int.
I have a List Of this class which the data looks like:

```
ID,   |   EmailActions
_______________
 A    |   1, 3, 5
 B    |   3, 5, 6
 C    |   2, 4, 6
```

I'm trying to write a Linq Statement To convert this into  A list of IDs grouped by each individual value in the list.

So the Results Set would look like:

```
ID   |   Values
_______________
 1    |   A
 2    |   C
 3    |   A, B
 4    |   C,
 5    |   A, B
 6    |   B, C
```

I can't figure out how I would write the group by can anyone give me some insight.

```
DistinctValues = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6};
TrackingInfo.Groupby(t => DistinctValues.foreach(d => 
                                           t.EmailActions.Contains(d))).Tolist()
```

This ofcourse isn't working any suggestions on how to do this using Linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its easy enough to get a distinct list of `EmailActions`

```
var distinctEmailActions = items.SelectMany(i => i.EmailActions).Distinct();
```

Then pivoting this is a little complex, but here it is:

```
var result = distinctEmailActions.Select(e => new { 
              ID=e, 
              Values = items.Where(i => i.EmailActions.Contains(e)).Select(i => i.ID) 
});
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/CQFDY66608

Comment: +1, I like the way you think. This is almost identical to what I came up with before looking at any of the answers. Unlike some of the other answers, there is no need for the extra `GroupBy` clause.

Comment: Plus, You also deciphered from the example to get the proper distinct

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `SelectMany`, but it's easier to use query syntax here:

```
var result = from item in source
             from action in item.EmailActions
             group item.ID by action into g
             select new { ID = g.Key, Values = g.ToList() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first generating a range using `Enumerable.Range`, and then matching `EmailActions`, like this:

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(1, 6)
    .SelectMany(v => TrackingInfo.Where(info => info.EmailActions.Contains(v)).Select(info => new { Id, Value = v }))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
    .Select(g => new {
        Id = g.Key
    ,   Values = g.Select(p => p.Id).ToList()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) & [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:-

```
var result = tracking.SelectMany(x => x.EmailActionIDs, 
                                    (trackObj, EmailIds) => new { trackObj, EmailIds })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.EmailIds)
                     .Select(x => new
                       {
                            ID = x.Key,
                            Values = String.Join(",", x.Select(z => z.trackObj.ID))
                       }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4G1piV).